# Can anonymous union be simply `const` (not `constexpr`)?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, language-lawyer, unions

In the following example, an anonymous `union` declares member `int i`, which is injected in the enclosing scope, and `const` precedes the union declaration:

```
int main() {
    const union {
        int i = 0;
    };
    i = 1;
}
```

The compilers diverge in handling of this program.

MSVC accepts union declaration, but rejects `i = 1` with the error:

> error C3892: '$S1': you cannot assign to a variable that is const

GCC accepts the whole program without any warning, simply ignoring the `const` prefix.

Clang in `-pedantic-errors` mode issues the error:

> anonymous union cannot be 'const' [-Werror,-Wpedantic]

[Online demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hnMfK5jKb)

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: AFAIK assiging to a union als "activates the member" which is changing the state of the object (union). I think this is the section that describes it : [expr.const.5.10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.10). Assigning to a non active member is not a constant expression. (IMO union's behaviour by now is just too complex, and use should be avoided in favor of std::variant)

Comment: Since an anonymous union does not declare variables of that type, and the leading `const` is not part of the union type, it makes sense for the leading `const` to be ignored/forbidden, IMHO.  The MSVC behavior is likely a Microsoft-specific extension. The leading `const` is not mentioned in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/unions?view=msvc-170#anonymous_unions), though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1702.html): the definition implies that no other *decl-specifier*s are allowed, contradicting the statements about storage class specifiers.  (I’m not sure what the point of a `const` anonymous union would be anyway.)